# How to generate synonyms for Solr

Tags: apache, solr, synonym

I recently started using Solr's Synonym filter factory to help improve prior education searches.

For example, if a user enters *New York University*, then they should get a hit on someone who just has *NYU* or *Stern Business School* in their bio.

Is there any particular method of aggregating these synonym clusters for the major universities in America? Or is there some broader method that isn't just copying and pasting from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

that depends:

1. if you are lucky, and have a large real world search corpus for your domain at your disposal (where that type of searches are done), then this could be done. Start by having a look at these two presentations: [one by Trey Greinger](http://www.treygrainger.com/posts/presentations/reflected-intelligence-lucene-solr-as-a-self-learning-data-system/) and [one by Simon Hughes](https://www.slideshare.net/lucidworks/implementing-conceptual-search-in-solr-using-lsa-and-word2vec-presented-by-simon-hughes-dicecom). The later is closer to be used, it has a github repo with code etc. The first one is more conceptual.
2. if you are not that lucky, then you can always do it manually (or crowdsource it, mechanical-turkify it...)